# Onclick on row grid with ZK over Grails

Tags: grails, zk, zul

I have a grid and its rows are programatically inserted by the composer. I would like to know which row is clicked.

The zul file.

```
<grid mold="paging" hflex="1" pageSize="10" id="gridBook">
    <columns>
        <column align="center">id</column>
        <column align="center">Title</column>
        <column align="center">Author</column>
    </columns>
</grid>
```

The composer

```
gridBook.append{
    rows{
        list.each{ e->
            row{
                label(value:e.id)
                label(value:e.title)
                label(value:e.author)
            }
        }                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Adding just the event method, in my case onClick

```
       list().each{ book->
            row{
                label(value:book.id)
                label(value:book.title)
                label(value:book.author)

            }.onClick{ event ->
                this.loadRow(book)
            }
        }
    def loadRow(book){
       //
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

en zk.........

`<row forward="onClick=onAnything" >`

and Java ( Composer)

`public void onAnything(ForwardEvent evt) throws Exception{
        Row row = (Row) evt.getOrigin().getTarget();
        System.out.println(" test "+row.getValue());
    }`